# in Parslet, how to reconstruct substrings from parse subtrees?

Tags: ruby, parslet

I'm writing a parser for strings with interpolated name-value arguments, e.g.: `'This sentence #{x: 2, y: (2 + 5) + 3} has stuff in it.'`  The argument values are code, which has its own set of parse rules.

Here's a version of my parser, simplified to only allow basic arithmetic as code:

```
require 'parslet'
require 'ap'
class TestParser < Parslet::Parser
  rule :integer do match('[0-9]').repeat(1).as :integer end
  rule :space do match('[\s\\n]').repeat(1) end
  rule :parens do str('(') >> code >> str(')') end
  rule :operand do integer | parens end
  rule :addition do (operand.as(:left) >> space >> str('+') >> space >> operand.as(:right)).as :addition end
  rule :code do addition | operand end
  rule :name do match('[a-z]').repeat 1 end
  rule :argument do name.as(:name) >> str(':') >> space >> code.as(:value) end
  rule :arguments do argument >> (str(',') >> space >> argument).repeat end
  rule :interpolation do str('#{') >> arguments.as(:arguments) >> str('}') end
  rule :text do (interpolation.absent? >> any).repeat(1).as(:text) end
  rule :segments do (interpolation | text).repeat end
  root :segments
end
string = 'This sentence #{x: 2, y: (2 + 5) + 3} has stuff in it.'
ap TestParser.new.parse(string), index: false
```

Since the code has its own parse rules (to ensure valid syntax), the argument values are parsed into a subtree (with parentheses etc. replaced by nesting within the subtree):

```
[
    {
        :text => "This sentence "@0
    },
    {
        :arguments => [
            {
                 :name => "x"@16,
                :value => {
                    :integer => "2"@19
                }
            },
            {
                 :name => "y"@22,
                :value => {
                    :addition => {
                         :left => {
                            :addition => {
                                 :left => {
                                    :integer => "2"@26
                                },
                                :right => {
                                    :integer => "5"@30
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        :right => {
                            :integer => "3"@35
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        :text => " has stuff in it."@37
    }
]
```

However, I want to store the argument values as strings, so this would be the ideal result:

```
[
    {
        :text => "This sentence "@0
    },
    {
        :arguments => [
            {
                 :name => "x"@16,
                :value => "2"
            },
            {
                 :name => "y"@22,
                :value => "(2 + 5) + 3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        :text => " has stuff in it."@37
    }
]
```

How can I use the Parslet subtrees to reconstruct the argument-value substrings?  I could write a code generator, but that seems overkill -- Parslet clearly has access to the substring position information at some point (although it might discard it).

Is it possible to leverage or hack Parslet to return the substring?

Comment: Can you expand on "code sections are parsed into a deep hash"? What is a "code substring (e.g. whitespace)"? And what is a "hash's Parslet slice"?

Comment: I understand this, but I do a lot of parsing.  The question could be improved with an example showing what you've tried with Parslet and explaining why that doesn't work for you.  Also, it might be good to explain why you need the exact substring contained in the `#{...}` interpolation block, whitespace and all.

Comment: @sawa this question is specifically about Parslet's code and data structures -- someone without working knowledge of Parslet isn't going to be able to help

Comment: @WayneConrad example added

Comment: @sawa hopefully the changes address your concerns, please reopen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the hack I ended up with.  There are better ways to accomplish this, but they'd require more extensive changes.  `Parser#parse` now returns a `Result`.  `Result#tree` gives the normal parse result, and `Result#strings` is a hash that maps subtree structures to source strings.

```
module Parslet

  class Parser
    class Result < Struct.new(:tree, :strings); end
    def parse(source, *args)
      source = Source.new(source) unless source.is_a? Source
      value = super source, *args 
      Result.new value, source.value_strings
    end
  end

  class Source
    prepend Module.new{
      attr_reader :value_strings
      def initialize(*args)
        super *args
        @value_strings = {}
      end
    }
  end

  class Atoms::Base
    prepend Module.new{
      def apply(source, *args)
        old_pos = source.bytepos
        super.tap do |success, value|
          next unless success
          string = source.instance_variable_get(:@str).string.slice(old_pos ... source.bytepos)
          source.value_strings[flatten(value)] = string
        end
      end    
    }
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

The tree produced is based on the use of `as` in your parser.

You can try removing them from anything in an expression so you get a single string match for the expression. This seems to be what you are after.

If you want the parsed tree for these expressions too, then you need to either:

- Transform the expression trees back to the matched text.
- Re-Parse the matched text back into an expression tree.

Neither of these is ideal, but if speed is not vital, I would go the re-parse option. ie. remove the `as` atoms, and then later reparse the expressions to trees as needed.

As you rightly want to reuse the same rules, but this time you need `as` captures throughout the rules, then you could implement this by deriving a parser from your existing parser and implementing rules with the same names in terms of `rule :x { super.x.as(:x)}`

OR

You could have a general rule for expression that matches the whole expression without knowing what is in it.

eg. `"#{" >> (("}".absent >> any) | "\\}").repeat(0)  >> "}"`

Then later you can parse each expression into a tree as needed. that way you are not repeating your rules. It assumes you can tell when your expression is complete without parsing the whole expression subtree.

Failing that, it leaves us with hacking parslet.

I don't have a solution here, just some hints.

Parslet has a module called "CanFlatten" that implements `flatten` and is used by `as` to convert the captured tree back to a single string. You are going to want to do something like this.

Alternatively you need to change the `succ` method in `Atom::Base` to return "[success/fail, result, consumed_upto_position]" so each match knows where it consumed up to. Then you can read from the source between the start position and end position to get the raw text back. The `current position` of the source at the point the parser matches should be the value you want.

Good Luck.

Note: My example expression parser doesn't handle escaping of the escape character.. (left as an exercise for the reader)

Comment: that's a good tip, but in another part of the app I _do_ need the tree.  I'd like to use the same set of parse rules in both scenarios instead of duplicating them

Comment: yeah, I'd rather not force the use of a `\}` escape character (Ruby's rich recursive interpolation has spoiled me). great idea about `rule :x { super.x.as(:x)}`.  I think that or hacking `succ` is about as good an answer as is possible.  thanks!